# Google Cloud VM Instance Stuck on resizing suggested by Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had a vm instance running on Google Cloud, it's suggested me that "you should resize instance to 2CPU and 16GB RAM from 4CPU and 16GB RAM".
I pressed to Apply to set new config. Instance has stopped and stucked in resize process since an hour, neigher shows resized in gcloud instance list nor starting up.

Even try for taking snapshot of that vm's disk shows error that "it's being used in some operations"

Tried to force stop via gcloud, but no luck. In notification pop-up shows, resizing vm only.

Pls help me here.

Comment: Got notification after an hour, "The zone 'projects/xyz-project-272905/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."
Hey, google, why didn't you check before stopping instance that you have 2CPU free not. Again Same resource issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for this issue is GCP resource availability which depends on users requests and therefore is dynamic. As result, issues like this could happen when you use cloud resources on-demand without reservation.

Let's have a look at **the cause of this issue**:

- when you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory;
- when you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back;
- when you resize your VM it's the same.

In case if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

```
    The zone 'projects/xyz-project-272905/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later..
```

more details you can find in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
>   or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
>   resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
>   request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
>   and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

**There are a few ways to solve your issue**:

- Move your instance to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) by following [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).
- Wait for a while and try to resize your VM instance again.
- [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future (*extra payment will be required*):

  > Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
  >   zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
  >   additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
  >   your workloads when you need them. *After you create a reservation, you
  >   begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
  >   available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
  >   is deleted.*